# how to make margin-bottom of inner img and margin-bottom of outer div collapse?

Tags: html, image, margin

i have an img inside a div. the img floats right and the text should surround it from the left and (if it's a long text) from the bottom like this:

```
text text:IMG
text text:IMG
text text::::
text text tex
:::::::::::::
```

the colons should represent the space (margin).

if it's a long text, everything's working fine. but if the text is too short to exceed the img's height, the result is sth like that:

```
text text:IMG
text text:IMG
         ::::
:::::::::::::
```

but should be sth like this:

```
text text:IMG
text text:IMG
:::::::::::::
```

so, how do I get the margin-bottom of the inner img and the margin-bottom of the outer div to collapse?

suppose that margin-collapsing doesnt work because of either the inner-outer-relation or because of that both margins are bottom-margins?

maybe relevant: I use box-sizing: border-box

thank you

CODE

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
    Some text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div img {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

my workaround:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
    <div>
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {

}

div img {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

div div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the div element is displaying as inline; you need the paragraph and the image to be a block,
so you should use display:inline-block, like this:

```
div {
margin-bottom: 10px;
display:inline-block;
}

div img {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dHPe6/)

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately it seems not to work. the two margin-borders do not collapse - replace margin with padding (it should work both ways and the visible output is the same) and give the div and the image different background-colors.